# c# Better way to retrieve large bulks of data from SQL Server 2014?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2014, sqlconnection

Context: I retrieve bulks of data to index them in an ElasticSearch cluster (it has no-sql format).

I do this by determining how many delegates do I need to create with a for loop depending of how many rows does the current analyzed table has compared to my `bulk_size`, and execute them to do the code below.

I use `offset-fetch`. `tb` represents the current table, and my current `bulk_size` is 5000.

My code looks like this:

```
using (SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(tb.Conn))
{
    int offset = i * BULK_SIZE;
    int nextRows = BULK_SIZE;

    string queryParams = string.Format(" ORDER BY {0} OFFSET {1} ROWS FETCH NEXT {2} ROWS ONLY", tb.FirstPK(), offset, nextRows);

    string dataQuery = string.Format("SELECT * FROM dbo.{0} {1}", tb.TableName, queryParams);

    try
    {
        db.Open();
        object[,] bulk = new object[BULK_SIZE, 2];//[data[], id]
        int n = 0;
        object[] values;

        using (SqlDataReader reader = new SqlCommand(dataQuery, db).ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string docId = string.Empty;

                foreach (string pk in tb.PKeys)
                {
                    docId += reader[pk].ToString() + '_';
                }

                docId = docId.Substring(0, docId.Length - 1);//delete last '_'
                values = new object[reader.FieldCount];

                reader.GetValues(values);

                bulk[n, 0] = values;
                bulk[n, 1] = docId;

                n++;
            }

            reader.Close();
        }

        db.Close();

        if (IsMemoryAvailable())//Waits for other delegates to finish
        {
            DataUpload(bulk, tb, mapper);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message); Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace); Console.ReadLine();
        //throw e;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

I get then bulk, insert it into an array and handle that bulk in another task.

The problem is that the memory of SQL Server keeps going up (cache goes too big), and in late-bulk-fetching I get timeout exceptions and such; it gets to slow.

Comment: I would suggest changing your `SELECT * FROM` to Selecting the actual columns that you need.. if you need 2 columns then don't use select * also change this query to be a stored procedure

Comment: What is the point of having Task.Run there? IMHO it just wastes one extra thread as the calling thread is still blocked by Wait(). Also, if code in that will throw exception, you will get AggregateException with no meaningfull message.

Comment: @KasparsOzols you are right; I had problems with encapsulating tasks in a `Task.WaitAll` call, but forgot to change it later.

Comment: Side note: I highly advocate using [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper). It will make your life so much easier. You can then utilize the `commandTimeout` parameter if necessary.

Comment: @Arman so Dapper is just basically a query Mapper based on POCO classes? What I do is create an object for every array of data representing a db row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to create a temp table with only the primary keys, and query back and forth from the table and the temp table with joins.

This is way more memory efficient than `offset-fetch`, and also faster.